# How can I integrate Python into an OSX program?

Tags: python, ios, osx

I'm very comfortable with Swift, Obj-C, and Javascript but for a new project I need to use a library that is only available in Python. How do I integrate python or python scripts into an OSX project?

There is the option of going PyObjc or pyapp to build the entire application but that seems extravagant given that I only need Python for a small portion of that program.

It seems the preferable route would be to push Python to the cloud. Is there a pre bundled solution for doing this or would it require me to set up my own environment?

Comment: [This seems relevant](http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/09/27/use-python-effectively-on-os-x).

Answer (score 2):

If the amount of data that needs to be passed is small, then for an OS X application, one can run some Python code via a system() shell command from Swift or Objective C code.

For iOS, unless you want to build a Python interpreter into your app, it may be best to push running the Python library and scripts to a server "in the cloud".

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. I'm just not sure the tool kit to do that. I often write cloud code in js, just not Python. Any stack suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For ways to embed Python code, see:

- [Embedding Python in Another Application](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html) and [a longer article on it](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497) and [a tech talk video on it](http://realmike.org/blog/2012/07/05/supercharging-c-code-with-embedded-python/)
- [Embedding Python using Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/embedding.html) and [a longer article about that](http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/EmbeddingPythonPart1.html)
- [Cython](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html) is an easy way to bridge Python with C family languages